# What is the best way of grouping OSGi bundles to make a coherent 'application'

Tags: osgi

The "OSGi way" is to develop separate bundles containing discrete, coherent pieces of functionality. Sometimes these bundles contain utility classes, sometimes they depend on utility classes and set up their own OSGi Services.

Users, on the other hand, are unlikely to be exposed to bundles. They care more about the *application*, a piece of software that performs a task or solves their problem. Normally an application will use multiple bundles (say, imported via Import-Package) to perform its tasks.

**What is the best way to formalise this relationship in the OSGi world?** One example requirement would be something as simple as showing the current version number *of the application* (not the bundle(s)) to to the user. How would this version number be discovered?

Eclipse has a concept called 'features' but this is not OSGi standard.

Peter Kriens has [written about OSGi applications](http://blog.osgi.org/2008/07/osgi-application-grouping.html) and his article makes sense. My take away from it was that an application can map to a bundle; it's just that the bundle uses other bundles in some way. But if one is to create an application bundle using Import-Package, I don't see how that can be feasible from a development point of view.

One way may be to have an 'application bundle' that uses Require-Bundle and has its own version, but Require-Bundle is frowned up in the OSGi world.

Using Import-Package to import all the required packages with the required versions, however, adds a **significant** maintenance overhead to the developer to the extent that I don't think it's feasible. Each time the smallest change is made, even to an implementation package, the package version must be updated, and then the dependency on the package version updated in the 'application bundle'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The framework is the application ... The biggest mistake imho in the OSGi world is to see OSGi as a multi-tenant framework, it was not designed for that purpose and it is not a good fit. Inside a framework, there is high cohesion, all services registered are **your** services. The architectural model of OSGi allows you to write applications from loosely coupled components wired through services. Which is imho by far the best it gets in software (though there are lots of missing components unfortunately, will come).

In bndtools we go out of our way to help with this model. A bndtools bndrun file is basically an application that you can deploy. bnd can turn this bndrun file into runnable Jar with a Main-Class manifest header. (And with JPM it will be easy to deploy on any system.)

So the workflow is basically: design your services (== architecture), find standard components, develop missing components, test the components, test the integration, and turn the whole thing into a runnable JAR (or WAR).

Obviously you can still run multiple frameworks inside a single VM if so desired, but never run different unrelated applications in the same framework, not a good idea, life is hard enough as it is.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting and important clarification that I didn't understand before. I've read about JPM on your blog and the concept sounds good, I'm basically doing this myself in an unholy collection of build scripts and installers. Looking forward to seeing how it turns out.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I wish were like that. But with the rise of Apache Karaf and Eclipse Virgo, a framework also contains a web server, like Pax Web which incorporates Jetty, running on a port. Now, owing to the servlet container way, it seems logical to run two or more web applications, in different context paths. Which means these applications need to reside in the same framework. The other alternative (that is more aligned with "all services are your services") is running each application in a separate Karaf instance, separate HTTP port, etc. What do you think ?

Comment: There are so many ways to skin this particular cat :-) Simplest solution is to put your OSGi framework in a WAR and use any app server. 
Second, you can easily proxy the HTTP service. This can range from within one process with multiple frameworks (just register the Http service in all frameworks when you launch them) up to each executable having its own (simple) HTTP server on a local port that is merged by a robust http server (which can provide a lot of nice central caching, security, other languages, url routing, and other features out of the box).

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you're looking for is 'subsystem', I think there is an OSGi draft spec. out there.

My personal view:

Build your bundles and store them somewhere (For example a Sonatype Nexus server, I'm pretty pleased with it, it even has support for OBR and a limited support for generating p2 data)

An 'application' is then a selection of bundles with a certain version out of that repository, which you can version again.

There is no real standard yet, I think at this point you'll need to pick one of the non standard ones out there. The cost of changing to the standard one or even support multiple ones shouldn't be all that great.

[These slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/subsystems-for-those-occasions-where-bundles-are-just-too-small-graham-charters) mention all of them

Comment: Thanks for introducing 'subsystems'. That slide deck does appear to cover my requirements, for instance Subsystem-Version. It's interesting that 'Subsystem-Content' declares bundles (and other things) rather than packages. Unfortunately my OSGi impl of choice, Felix, doesn't appear to have a subsystem concept.

Comment: You could consider Apache Karaf, that uses Felix underneath (although I think it can also run using Equinox). The Karaf features are simple to use and as far as I can see pretty much what you want. The usage of mvn:/ style URL's is also clever.

Comment: Subsystems is very new (the spec only went final last month) and so you won't find any stable implementations yet. Also IMHO it's way too complicated... are you really deploying multiple isolated applications into a single OSGi framework?

Comment: Yeah there's lots of provision for different use cases and granularities there. I really just want to group a few bundles.

Comment: I also recommend to use karaf features for now if you use Apache Karaf. We are also working on integrating the subsystem spec into Karaf. So you could later transition to the standard way.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a resolver such as OBR or the new R5 resolver then using `Import-Package` does not necessarily create a large maintenance overhead.

However, the `Require-Bundle` way is also possible. An "application" typically consists of a small number (say, 1-5) "interesting" bundles. Then there are all the rest such as dependencies, SCR, Blueprint, etc. You could therefore create a single top-level Application bundle that uses `Require-Bundle` to refer to the small set of interesting bundles, and then all other dependencies are specified with `Import-Package`.

Comment: So do you think this is a legitimate use of Require-Bundle? All of my dependencies so far use Import-Package because I've read and understood what that is best practice. I thought the retention of Require-Bundle was mainly legacy support for Eclipse.

Comment: I do regard this as a legitimate use-case for `Require-Bundle`, yes. I believe that Peter Kriens agrees. Basically for "real" dependencies that come from your Java classes, you must always use `Import-Package`.... but here you are creating a kind of fake dependency purely for assembling things together into an application.

Comment: I also just want to address what you said about OBR and Import-Package, because I want to make sure I understand. I do already use OBR and also Import-Package for all dependencies between bundles. Now, an 'application' is made up of all model AND implementation bundles. It has to be like this because the implementation ultimately is what makes an application (!). Workflow coming up in the next comment...

Comment: This would be my workflow: 1) Update code in an impl package (2) increment minor version of impl package (3) increment version of impl bundle (4) increment version req on impl package in app bundle (5) increment version of app bundle so OBR will update it (otherwise if versions are same then OBR ignores it). Is that right? Maybe (3) can be removed?

Comment: I'm not sure about this because you're using OBR a different way from me. I use a resolver to prepare my runtime before launching it, I don't try to install/upgrade with OBR in the runtime. So the stuff about bumping versions purely to force OBR to reload sounds dodgy and unnecessary to me.

Comment: I think there is nothing 'evil' about Require-Bundle if you really want to specify a dependency to a bundle. As for OBR, I think it's usefulness depends on how you want to deploy your updates.

Comment: @Neil I'm wondering how bndtools would help with the versioning? Would it remove steps 2, 3 and 5?

Comment: One further problem with using Require-Bundle is, of course, it doesn't support fragments which are a part of an application.

Comment: That's true, you could use `Provide/Require-Capability` instead.

Comment: Require-Bundle is not evil if the requirerer is a leaf (nobody depends on it). The evilness of Require-Bundle is caused by its transitive nature. Components requiring other components create the big ball of mud problem and basically kill reuse. This problem is well known in Object Oriented systems and translates directly to components. Services/Packages do exactly what interfaces did for objects (alleviating the transitive coupling).

Comment: @NeilBartlett Looks like bindex doesn't support Provide/Require-Capability, so I don't see an easy way of generating the repository.xml right now. Was considering providing a patch but the project seems a little dead on github... osgi/bindex

Comment: @DanGravell I'm the maintainer of bindex so if you provide a good patch I'll accept it. However most of the work right now is going into bindex2 (on branch rfc112) that implements the new R5 repository format.

Comment: @NeilBartlett thanks. Looks like support for Provide/Require-Capability is there? https://github.com/osgi/bindex/blob/rfc112/org.osgi.impl.bundle.bindex2.lib/src/org/osgi/service/indexer/impl/BundleAnalyzer.java . I do have 'bindex-2.2.jar' as provided by apt-get but this doesn't appear to contain the support.

Comment: The rfc112 branch builds "bindex2" which is the R5 format. There is no support for Provide/Require-Capability in "bindex1" which generates the old OBR format. "bindex-2.2" is actually version 2.2 of "bindex1", there's been no release yet of "bindex2"... which I guess I should rename to avoid this confusion! By the way this thread is too long for stackoverflow, we should talk by email.